# Android - Why the string returned by getResources().getStringArray cannot be used in if clause?

Tags: java, android

My arrays.xml:

```
<string-array name="chart_names">
        <item>abc</item>
</string-array>
```

My testing code:

```
String[] chartNames = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.chart_names);

if ("abc" == chartNames[0]) {
  Log.v("msg", "yes");
}else{
  Log.v("msg", "no");
}
```

I always get false, so the console always prints "no".

Why does this happened ? It's really strange.....

Please help me....... Thanks.

Comment: omg.... your comparison is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is use equals() to compare strings or any objects

Try this code:

```
String[] chartNames = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.chart_names);

if (chartNames[0].equals("abc")) {
  Log.v("msg", "yes");
}else{
  Log.v("msg", "no");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.equals()` to compare two Strings

refer [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Answer (score 1):

for compare two string you can use .compareTo() or .equals() functions, of course using .equals() function is better.

*.equals():

```
if ("text1 to compare".equals("text2 to compare")) {
  Log.v("equal", "yes");
}else{
  Log.v("equal", "no");
}
```

*.compareTo()

```
if(str1.compareTo("str2")==0){
Log.v("equal", "yes");
}
```

Note: 
"foo".equals((String)null) returns false while "foo".compareTo((String)null) == 0 throws a NullPointerException